# moving user from multiple ADgroup to others with powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

[image: exemple of command]i have a csv file formatted like this

> oldniveau1,oldniveau2,oldniveau3,newniveau1,newniveau2,newniveau3

> 0UA_Ventes,CIS countries,Contracts,0UA_Ventes,CIS countries,Contracts_1

[image]
my goal is to extract active directory group name by formatting the path given in csv file

i have a script that work i give all the line in sigle variable but wheni use the loop i have error message

```
$csv=Import-Csv $pth\filerN3.csv -Delimiter ","  | Foreach-Object { 

  
$n1 = $_.oldniveau1
$n2 = $_.oldniveau2
$n3 = $_.oldniveau3
$n4 = $_.newniveau1
$n5 = $_.newniveau2
$n6 = $_.newniveau3

$adminn3group = "m^" + $n1 + "^" + $n2 + "^" + $n3 
$newadmingroup= "m^" + $n4 + "^" + $n5 + "^" + $n6
$writegroup= "g^" + $n1 + "^" + $n2 + "^" + $n3  
$newwritegroup="g^" + $n4 + "^" + $n5 + "^" + $n6  
$readgroup="g^" + $n1 + "^" + $n2 + "^" + $n3 + "^R"  
$newreadgroup="g^" + $n4 + "^" + $n5 + "^" + $n6 + "^R"  

$currentmanagermembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $adminn3group  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $newadmingroup -Members $currentmanagermembers  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue


Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $adminn3group -Members $currentmanagermembers -confirm:$false -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
###############
    Get-ADGroupMember $writegroup |
    Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership `
        -MemberOf $newwritegroup 
 
Get-ADGroupMember $writegroup  |
    Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership `
        -MemberOf $writegroup -confirm:$false -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
###############
Get-ADGroupMember $readgroup |
    Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership `
        -MemberOf $newreadgroup 
 
Get-ADGroupMember $readgroup |
    Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership `
        -MemberOf $readgroup -confirm:$false -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

        ########"


}
```

so without the loop for the csv when i use  6 variable to fix each one it work and all the user are moved

but with  the loop

i have this error any idea why ?

```
Get-ADGroupMember : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At C:\temp\addN3MGR\move_central.ps1:28 char:54
+ ... entmanagermembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $adminn3group  -Error ...
+                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-ADGroupMember], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember
 
Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again.
At C:\temp\addN3MGR\move_central.ps1:30 char:29
+ Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $newadmingroup -Members $currentmanagerme ...
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-ADGroupMember], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGroupMember
```

Comment: Can you please edit and properly format your post. There is currently way too many errors. They all indicate that no groups are being found hence, "*The argument is null or empty.*". I've never seen any group name use `m^` let alone `^`, so I would recommend just running a query against one of your concatenated strings to see if anything is returned.

Comment: Get-ADGroupMember  -Identity "g^0UA_Ventes^Briefs_Conferences^Briefs^R"

Comment: this return user that are in the ad group

Comment: What about your first query according to your csv: `Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "m^0UA_Ventes^CIS countries^Contracts"`

Comment: @AbrahamZinala when i launch all the single command line by line it work but in the loop they are like empty identity i ve cheked the variable by redirecting them to text and chek the outpout it's good this is making me crazy

Comment: PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "m^0UA_Ventes^CIS countries^Contracts"


distinguishedName : CN=Gon Irina,OU=CU_0UAKIE,OU=people,DC=corp,DC=noxiane,DC=net
name              : Gon Irina
objectClass       : user
objectGUID        : edf80e64-5ea9-4a8a-9577-21d828b556f1
SamAccountName    : ax06954
SID               : S-1-5-21-1608400361-1401040151-28319967-870508

Comment: To me, it just seems that the name is the issue. That error indicates a group by that name cannot be found. Implement a `try{}catch{}`  for a streamlined process. Better yet, just have your script write to the console with the variables and see which one it errors out on. Then test it individually.

Comment: i alerady had my script write to the console with the variable it work if it's only not in the loop . when i fix my varaible oncve at a time

Comment: It looks as if you have empty values in your CSV file.. Are you sure you show us exactly how the CSV is formatted? Please open it in Notepad first, then copy the first 3 lines and [paste](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71416136/edit) that into your question as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: i have found the issue it was related to security group without member i have changed the way the command format and it worked

Comment: Hello @Wissem Rekaya,Can you plese post it answer. So it could help other community member if they encounter the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to empty member for some security group so I changed the command were processed and it worked

I'm a beginner in Powershell and not very comfortable yet with `try` and `catch`.

```
Get-ADGroup  $adminn3group  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue|Get-ADGroupMember | % {Add-ADGroupMember $newadmingroup -Members $_ }

Get-ADGroup $adminn3group -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue|Get-ADGroupMember | % {Remove-ADGroupMember $adminn3group -Members $_ -confirm:$false} 

Get-ADGroup  $writegroup  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue|Get-ADGroupMember | % {Add-ADGroupMember $newwritegroup -Members $_ }
 
Get-ADGroup $writegroup -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue|Get-ADGroupMember | % {Remove-ADGroupMember $writegroup -Members $_ -confirm:$false} 

Get-ADGroup  $readgroup  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue|Get-ADGroupMember | % {Add-ADGroupMember $newreadgroup -Members $_ }

Get-ADGroup $readgroup -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue|Get-ADGroupMember | % {Remove-ADGroupMember $readgroup -Members $_ -confirm:$false}
```